# How to generate a front end ID for an element in order to retrieve it with an AJAX request?

Tags: python, ajax, django, google-app-engine

What are best practices to generate action links in order to retrieve elements from the front end ?

For example, the user opened a page describing a specific project. A project is represented by an entity which has a key we use to fetch it from the Datastore. How do we generate a link that make us able to send an AJAX request that identify the resource we want to get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve an entity from the datastore you cab pass along an encoded version of the key to the client side quite easily with ndb.

EG:

```
ajax_safe_representation_of_key = entity.key.urlsafe()

# to retrieve that key
key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=ajax_safe_representation_of_key)
entity = key.get()
```

Comment: Be cautious with this approach. Understand that anyone can decode this urlsafe form of key, and see information that you may not want to disclose.

Comment: The only information we can see from this url is information about the key (e.g "Key('EntityKind', 123456)"). Not anyone can fetch it from the Datastore. I don't see a big security issue there but if it is required, I will consider encrypting the url.